# SSL/TLS Connector configuration not working for host for jboss

Tags: java, server, jboss, web-deployment

I am trying to implement SSL for my application using jboss. Below is the implementation in server.xml file.

```
 <Service name="jboss.web"
      className="org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.StandardService">

      <!-- A HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 80
      <Connector port="80" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
         maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
         enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
         connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"/> -->

      <!-- A AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
      <Connector port="8809" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
         enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" debug="0"
         protocol="AJP/1.3"/>

      <!-- SSL/TLS Connector configuration using the admin devl guide keystore-->
        <Connector port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
            maxThreads="100" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="15"
            scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"
            keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/chap8.keystore"
            keystorePass="rmi+ssl" sslProtocol = "TLS" />
```

This configuration is working for 'https://localhost:8443' on server but not using my domain eg.'https://test-example.com:8443'.

Answer (score 0):

Please test using this configuration as i have added the SSLEnabled = "true".As it is mandatory

```
<!-- SSL/TLS Connector configuration using the admin devl guide keystore -->
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
    maxThreads="100" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="15"
    scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"
    keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/chap8.keystore"
    keystorePass="rmi+ssl" sslProtocol = "TLS" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.It is still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If localhost works but not the domain name, then it's probably because the ${jboss.bind.address} is 127.0.0.1. Verify that you're binding the server's IP and not the loopback.